# Base64 encoding in Swift will not decode in Android

Tags: android, ios, image, swift, base64

I have an Android app which uses Base64 to encode images, and encoded strings are stored on a server. I am now making an iOS client for the same app and am struggling to make it encode images in the same way
Images encoded on the android end will decode in Swift iOS but images encoded in Swift will NOT decode in Android, or here http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html (the resulting file isn't a valid image)

Images encoded in iOS WILL decode in iOS

In Android, I am using the following to encode and decode

```
public static String encodeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap immagex = bitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(String encodedString) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0,
            decodedByte.length);
    return b;
}
```

And the following on the iOS side

```
static func decodeImage(str: String) -> UIImage?{
    if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: str, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters){
        var iconValue:UIImage? = UIImage(data: decodedData)
        return iconValue
    }
    return nil
}

static func encodeImage(image: UIImage) -> String{
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64 = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding76CharacterLineLength)
    return base64
}
```

}

I am willing to change either client to make it work

Example:
take this image for example
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/522909800191901697/FHCGSQg0.png

On Android it encodes to http://pastebin.com/D41Ldjis

And on iOS to http://pastebin.com/fEUZSJvF

iOS one has a much larger character count

Comment: every example I see with swift shows this `imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)`

Comment: @tyczj I have tried that too, i tried 76 because i noticed the string produced by android has new lines every 76th character

Comment: Add an example, data hex dump and Base64 string. Have you compared them at all visually? Are the lengths the same? Are they being URL encoded on transfer?

Comment: @zaph ok. What is a hex dump? Visually they are nothing alike. I checked visual alikeness before transferring, from the output of println. Ill add example now

Comment: Hmm??? Googling [hex dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump). That was not to hard.

Comment: @zaph ive added exmaples

Comment: @HamzahMalik I think you need update your question because problem is in PNG binary data you send to base64 encoder

Comment: Actually close this question and ask another just about iOS PNG encoding, a new title will help. Consider that the question about Base64 encoding is answered, that there is no problen with it. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Base64 provoided are from different PNG encodings. The headers are different, Android has a "sBIT" chunk and iOS has a "sRGB" chunk.

Thus the problem is not Base64 but the representatins prpovided by the two systems.

Decoded portions

> Android:
>   âPNG

IHDR††≠zsBIT€·O‡ÑIDAT

> iOS:
>   âPNG

IHDR»»≠XÆûsRGBÆŒÈiDOTd(ddp`ùıºIDAT

Comment: How would I then solve this? Is there a way to force one to use the encoding of the other?

Comment: @zaph better provide hex values instead of ascii

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I want to present, the only thing I am interested in are the chunk tags which are in ASCII: PNG, IHDR, sBIT, sRGB and IDAT.

Comment: Note: The Android Base64 decoded and produces the desired image, the iOS version does not.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Surely the 'fault' is in iOS encoding?

Comment: @HamzahMalik The falut is in the iOS image encoding, not the Base64 encoding. Different data is being Base64 encoded.