# iOS UIImagePNGRepresentation base64 encode not giving expected output

Tags: android, ios, base64, uiimagepngrepresentation

The code

```
static func encodeImage(image: UIImage) -> String{
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64 = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
    return base64
}
```

Does not return the expected output, when the resulting String is decoded in Java or using online tools, the reproduced image is not a valid PNG file

This answer here [Base64 encoding in Swift will not decode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082525/base64-encoding-in-swift-will-not-decode-in-android) suggests that the problem is not in the encoding but that the actual PNG is a different format to the one used by Android, iOS seems to use sRGB and Android sBIT

Is there any way to make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had issues as welll with converting images to base64. But that is due to not all signs get escaped correctly. So I made a small function for it that always works for me:

```
func imageToBase64(imageToDecode: UIImage!) -> String {
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToDecode, 0.8)
    var base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    base64String = base64String.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    base64String = base64String.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "%2F", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    return base64String
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, will accept this answer after timeout

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Comment: However, iOS will not decode this image back again, what code are you using for decoding on iOS

Comment: I don't have any. As soon as I send it to the API I am working with, it gets uploaded and from that point I just get a URL when I request the image. But I can see if I can program something if you haven't figured it out yet?

Comment: You can ignore my earlier comment about it not decoding back, it does, the error was a logic error

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have tried to found a solution for this. This one helped me lot.